# Controller Action method return string or Redirect to another action with ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am calling MVC action method through jquery ajax post. This action method will either return a string value or if certain condition in action method is true it will redirect to another action method. The problem is whenever i am trying to redirect to another action method the ajax post is executing the error block and whenever the action method is returning a string value it works fine. I don't want to use html form post. Below is my code:

```
 function VerifyCreds() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Login/Verify",
        data: '{Username: "' + $("#txtUsername").val() + '",Password: "' + $("#txtPassword").val() + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}

public ActionResult Verify(string Username, string Password)
    {
        string Response = "0";
        EmployeeEntities ent = new EmployeeEntities();
        var val = ent.VerifyUser(Username, Password);
        Response = val.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        if (Response == "1")
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction("LandingPage");
        }
        return Content(Response);
    }
    public ActionResult LandingPage()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly specifying `json` as the data type. that means, your ajax method expects the response from the server as a json string. The jQuery ajax method will use `JSON.parse` method to create a JavaScript object from this json string and pass it to the callback. When you do a redirect from server, it is not returning a 200 OK response back, but a 302 redirect response back  and browser will usually makes a new call to the location header value of the response. You are getting the error callback of the ajax method because the server is returning some string which cannot be safely converted to a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse`. (My guess is that the response for the LandingPage call!. Check the network tab to see what response is coming)

If you absolutely want to handle this situation, you may better return a proper JSON structure in both the cases and inspect this json data at client side and do a redirect as needed.

I also suggest you to use the appropriate types. Use `int` instead of storing a number in a `string` variable.

```
public ActionResult Verify(string Username, string Password)
{       
    var ent = new EmployeeEntities();
    var val = ent.VerifyUser(Username, Password);
    var response = val.FirstOrDefault();
    if (response == 1)
    {
       return Json(new { status="redirect", url = Url.Action("LandingPage")});      
    }
    return Json(new { status="success", message = "Valid login" });
}
```

and in the success event of your ajax call, inspect this json data and based on the `status` property, do a redirect or show a message to the user.

```
success: function (response) {
            if(response.status==="redirect")
            {
                window.location.href = response.url;
            }
            else
            {
                alert(response.message);
            }
        },
```

You can also totally remove `dataType: "json",` from your ajax call. jQuery will intelligently guess the type based on the response headers and use that. Since we are explicitly returning Json from our action method, the response Content-Type header value will be `application/json`