# Redirect to another action after submit using Malsup Ajax Form

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can I redirect page to another action when upload is complete? As of now `status.html(xhr.responseText);` creates a "partial" view of Index inside the Create view when upload is complete. As of now the Create action returns a JsonResult with the url I want the page to redirect to.

```
<script>
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var bar = $('.progress-bar');
        var percent = $('.percent');
        var status = $('#status');

        $('#Myform').ajaxForm({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            beforeSend: function () {
                status.empty();
                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            complete: function (xhr) {
                window.location.href = xhr.url;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Create action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateVideoViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Video video = new Video();

            if (model.File != null)
            {
                // ....

                if (videoUpload != null && thumbnailUpload != null)
                {
                    return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index", new { projectId = model.ProjectId }) });
                }

                return View("Error");
            }

            return View("Error");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Index action

```
public ActionResult Index(string projectId)
        {
            IndexVideoViewModel model = new IndexVideoViewModel
            {
                Project = db.Projects.Where(project => project.Id == projectId).First()
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: It does not make any sense to return a redirect response back to an ajax call. The whole idea of using ajax is to make partial page updates. If that is not what your intention is, why not do a normal form submit instead of ajax ?

Comment: Ok, I see. I do need Ajax calls for the progress bar to update, and it's working fine. What Im not able to do is to have the page redirect to the Index action when the upload of the file has completed..

Comment: Try `window.location.href="yourNextPageUrl"` inside the `complete` handler.

Comment: I tried and it makes an redirection to another page which is nice. But I cant seem to figure out how to get the full URL of my Index action method. I guess I could use @Url.Action() as value for href but then it would always redirect to Index when the Ajax has finished. I want the Create action to return the URL so in case there was an error, it should redirect to View("Error") or if the ModelState is not valid I want to redirect to View(model).

Comment: You can use Url.Action in your other action method to generate the url. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566053/controller-action-method-return-string-or-redirect-to-another-action-with-ajax-p/51566323#51566323) for an example

Comment: I changed so that the Create action returns a JsonResult with the url (I updated the question above). Though the redirection does not work. It seems xhr.url is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178309/discussion-between-slamdunk-and-shyju).